# vba excel type mismatch when returning full path workbook object

Tags: excel, vba, variables, path, type-mismatch

Type mismatch: It will always return a type mismatch error.

```
dim FileName_A As Workbook    
dim v_value as string *or any other type, ie, variant, long, integer...*
    
Set FileName_A = Workbooks.Open(strFile) *any EXCEL file xls*
    
v_value = Workbooks(FileName_A).Sheets("ABC").Cells("E3").Value
```

*E3 value is 01.1234 but will always return a type mismatch*

What am i missing here?
txs for your support.

Comment: Hi, VBasic2008. Indeed, i have tried with both Text and Value options. Adding CStr at the beginning still returns a type mismatch error. I must say that i have defined a "dim fullPathFileName_A As Workbook   ".

Comment: No special formatting in cells, just simple strings.

Comment: Try replacing `Cells` with `Range` because Cells would take a row index and column index rather than an A1-format address

Comment: Hi, barrowc. I have tried changing Cells with Range, but still get the same type mismatch error.

Comment: I have replaced the variable FileName_A with the real file name in the line:
v_value = Workbooks("mySheet.xls").Sheets("ABC").Cells("E3").Value    
and it works.
Therefore, that variable is not passing its value to this line. Why not?

Comment: `Dim v_value As String: v_value = CStr(FileName_A.Sheets("ABC").Range("E3").Value)` That was an unexpectedly great number of mistakes in only one line. The error was occurring because the `Workbooks property` was expecting the workbook name (a string) or the workbook index (a whole number) but you were passing it a `workbook object`.

Comment: Yes, indeed. I have adjusted and added ".name" to it, and keeping Range instead of Cells, and it works!

 v_value = Workbooks(fullPathFileName_A.name).Sheets("ABC").Range("E3").value

Txs, VBasic2008 and Barrowc. Really appreciated.

Comment: `FileName_A` holds a reference to the workbook, not just the workbook name.  `v_value = FileName_A.Sheets("ABC").Cells("E3").Value` should work.